# sub level set of a diifferentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $J:\Bbb R \to [0,\infty)$ be a differentiable function. Is it true that there exisct $C >0$ suct that $\{\nabla J =0\} \subset \{J \leq C\}$

Comment: Why would that be true? Let $J$ climb, then level off for a bit, then climb again, then level off, ...

Answer (score 0):

No - take $f(x) = |\sin(x-\pi)+x|$.